# Is Elbow Cay (Bahamas) walkable?

Tags: safety, walking, bahamas

I am travelling to Elbow Cay (Bahamas) in the coming months and am wondering the degree to which it's walkable. I've looked at Google street scenes, and it does not appear that many (or *any*) of the main streets have sidewalks. But it also appears that golf carts are one of the main forms of transportation, which seems to me like a safer environment to walk.

Is walking a practical form of transportation on Elbow Cay, or is golf cart and/or car the only way?

Comment: Note that Google StreetView in the area is from 2020, probably quite soon after the area got hit pretty badly by a hurricane. That could affect the number of people around, including the number of people walking along roads or even riding bicycles. It might be quite different at the moment.